# What is the reason of this error in Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a problem with the crystal reports.I have a report in which four tables are bound as source to the tables.In those 4 tables one table database fields are used in the formula fields.When I set that formula field on the report I am getting error this error "Unknown Database Connector Error" in the Preview Report.

Suppose when I remove that field or comment the formula code of that field we are not suppose to get that error.I don't understand that error too.

I have written like this in the formula field

```
 if{students.name} = "" then

    else
    "Student Name : " + {students.name}
```

I have googled alot but no use.Can any one help me regarding this ?

Comment: i've not seen the error before. what is your datasource? also that formula looks wrong- i think it should at least be: `if {students.name} = "" then "" else "Student Name : " + {students.name}` (and make sure you have nulls set to default not except).

Comment: As said by @LeeTickett try re-writing your formula.. you can try re-writing like this `if not {student.name}="" then "Student Name : "+{student.name}`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to install the crystal report for .NET framework 64 bit software.I will be solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If Not(Isnull({students.name})) Then
  "Student Name : " + {students.name}
```

Comment: Hi craig, I have tried as ou have mentioned but no use.I found a strange thing that I have runned the report in another machine also where I am not getting any error.